# Cinema 4D Generative Plane using audio file

Tags: 3d, cinema4d

In Cinema 4D I am looking to create an object that is developed through audio file. As the song plays I want it to displace the shape and by the end give me an object that is deformed by the music. I have gotten so far in creating something similar using imported sound, displacer tag and expresso on an object, however, this is animated and constantly changes form rather than generating into a final form.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You get better results using another method.

Make voice effector child to the plane object. Set the voice effector deformation to "Point" under the deformer tab. Also set the effector Apply Mode to "Step" under the Effector tab. That's it.